# Oracle Cloud Instance Linux 8.5 -- Unable to Fix Corrupted SSH Key

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oraclelinux

I have Oracle Linux 8.5 in Oracle Cloud, and have been using the host for several months.

But today I was trying to setup vscode remote ssh and looks like I messed up the ssh key that I use to login to the host. Now I cannot!

I tried to follow this [documentation](https://blogs.oracle.com/cloud-infrastructure/post/recovering-opc-user-ssh-key-on-oracle-cloud-infrastructure) and this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766048/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-lvm2-member) to fix some commands.

However, that did not help! And in fact now the host having difficulty stopping quickly; rebooting looks fine.

Any ideas on how to correct this issue?! (Was having a lot of fun until this struck :) )

Answer (score 1):

In the OCI console, go to the instance, and click on the "console connection", this will show you 2 options, one is create local connection, which will allow you to upload a new ssh key file. Or you can create a console connection and then update the authorized_keys file with your new id_rsa.pub contents

Answer (score 0):

Console connection did NOT work for me. That's why I went by attaching the volume to another instance. The [documentation](https://blogs.oracle.com/cloud-infrastructure/post/recovering-opc-user-ssh-key-on-oracle-cloud-infrastructure) I followed suggests to mount /dev/sdb3. However that did not work for me. Instead, I mounted /dev/ocivolume/root, and modified the ssh key there, and now works!